# Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',,Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the error in the screenshot below. The add-migration initial code was successful.
Then, when I say update-database, I get the error on the screen.
My migration code is below.can you help me?Could there be a problem with my product class?

[enter image description here][1]

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Categories",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    UpdatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Categories", x => x.Id);
                });][1]

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Product",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(200)", maxLength: 200, nullable: false),
                Stock = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2", nullable: false),
                CategoryID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                UpdatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Product", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Product_Categories_CategoryID",
                    column: x => x.CategoryID,
                    principalTable: "Categories",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ProductFeautre",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Color = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                Height = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Width = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                ProductID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
```

Comment: The image you uploaded cannot be displayed, please re-upload it so that you can locate the problem more accurately, and from the error message, you can check whether there is an error near the NOT field.

Comment: Well, it probably *can* be displayed, but you deleted the URL, so we will never know where it is :)

Answer (score 0):

In your product table, the price field decimal(18,2's statement is missing a closing parenthesis and should be decimal(18,2):

```
Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
```

If the error persists, you can provide more detailed error information.